# CF2018 empty admin page responses

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I recently installed CF2018 update 9. IIS is serving the applications I had in virtual directories normally, with the exception of CFIDE. Attempts to access `localhost/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm` result in empty HTTP responses, with `Content-Length:0` headers. The admin page *is* accessible through `localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`, which is (I think) just reaching out Tomcat directly. So I am wondering if anyone knows what the culprit for a blank administrator page when served via IIS might be? It worked before the update.

FWIW I have checked the handler mappings and they point to the same DLL as the applications that are properly being served (that is, `.../ColdFusion2018/config/wsconfig/1/isapi_redirect.dll`).

Comment: Is `CFIDE` added as virtual dir to the `Default Web Site`?

Comment: yes indeed it is

Comment: Are Detailed Errors turned on? What's the status code returned on the blank page?

Comment: not certain about detailed errors; but the status code is 200 so the server appears to think everything is fine. If I put static HTML files in the CFIDE directory it *does* serve those.

Comment: my problem might be a feature: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/coldfusion-administrator-is-not-being-served-up-by-iis/td-p/9354555?page=1

Comment: I think you would need a virtual directory for it to work that way.  localhost on port 80 I would assume is going to IIS then the CF Admin is using Tomcat on port 8500.  But I actually never tried to make the admin display via IIS ever since they did the change to it coming up via Tomcat.

Comment: You could try using the web server configuraiton tool to detach and reattach CF to IIS

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a site to IIS first, call it cf-admin or similar.
You need to add a second connector to WCONFIG located here:
/cfusion/runtime/bin/wsconfig.exe (run as admin).

Click ADD
Leave drop downs as they are, changing the bottom one "IIS Website" to the site you just created.

Click OK and OK again to restart
Expand the site in IIS you just created, right click the /jakarta vdir and check the location.

Open (location from above) /uriworkermap.properties
Remove the "!" from last line, so it reads /CFIDE/* = cfusion
Restart IIS and CF.

browse to the host header as configured when you created the site in IIS.